# How to get the total of the list ordered, with Javascript

Tags: javascript

I'm making a code of a online delivery webpage, and I having a hard time trying to figure out how to output the total of the list ordered by the user.

```
function ListOrder(){
        document.getElementById('order').innerHTML += "<div id=\"YourOrders\">" +  + document.getElementById('FoodName').value + document.getElementById('quantity').value  + document.getElementById('Totality').value + "</div><br>";}
```

Edited: I want to know how I can get the sum of the total price. So, I placed a parseInt between the document.getElementById('Totality').value . It looks like this now,

```
function ListOrder(){
        document.getElementById('order').innerHTML += "<div id=\"YourOrders\">" +  + document.getElementById('FoodName').value + document.getElementById('quantity').value  + parseInt(document.getElementById('Totality').value) + "</div><br>";}
```

Can someone help me make a function or something for that? Javascript only, please. I'm still kinda new at it.

Comment: Make sure you're operating on numbers. `.value` returns a string.

Comment: Oh, so how can I convert it to an integer?

Comment: @user3359381 `parseInt()`

Comment: @user3359381 You'll need to post more relevant code and a clearer description of how your actual output differs from your expected output if you'd like to have this question reopened.

Answer (score 0):

```
function ListOrder(){
  document.getElementById('order').innerHTML +=
    "<div id=\"YourOrders\">" +
    parseInt(document.getElementById('FoodName').value) +
    parseInt(document.getElementById('quantity').value) +
    parseInt(document.getElementById('Totality').value) +
    "</div><br>";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

the kernel of your code should look like the following (double `+` operator deleted, reformatted):

```
function ListOrder(){
    document.getElementById('order').innerHTML +=
          "<div id=\"YourOrders\">" +  (
                document.getElementById('FoodName').value
              + document.getElementById('quantity').value
              + document.getElementById('Totality').value
          )
        + "</div><br>"
    ;
}
```

You've phrased your question in a way that suggests you wish to output an order list assembled from the content of all (html) elements with certain ids.

this won't work reliably:

- Ids should be document unique.
- The Js functions you use do not iterate over lists.

instead, proceed along the following lines (which assume that you import [jquery](http://jquery.com), a cross-browser dom-handling and ajax library (which you should use anyway :)):

```
function ListOrder(){
    var e_orders = $("<div id=\"YourOrders\">");
    $("#order").append(e_orders);

    $(".FoodName").each ( function ( idx_fn, e_fn ) {
        $(e_orders).append(
            $("<div/>").append(
                 $(e_fn).val()
               + $(e_fn).nextAll('.quantity').val()
               + $(e_fn).nextAll('.Totality').val()
            );
        );
        $(e_orders).append("<br>");
    });

    return e_orders;
}
```

The code template assumes that the source data are elements with `value` attributes being marked with css classes `quantity`, `Totality` and 'FoodName``, that these elements are siblings and unique within a container element for each item incl. quantity information. It should be flexible enough to be tailored to your actual needs and html structure.